# Extracting common logic to a reusable function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given that I have:

```
$(function(){
  $("a[data-toggle-description-length]='toggle'").click(function(event){
    // common part:
    event.preventDefault();
    $("span.show_hide").toggleClass("shown hidden");
    $("table").toggleClass("wide narrow");
    $.get('/toggle_full_details');
  }); 
});

$(function(){
  $("a[data-toggle-description-length-refocus]='toggle'").click(function(event){
    event.preventdefault();
    $("span.show_hide").toggleClass("shown hidden");
    $("table").toggleclass("wide narrow");
    $("input[type='text']:first").focus();   // focus
    $.get('/toggle_full_details');
  }); 
});
```

How can I extract the common logic to a function?

I tried:

```
$(function update-ui(event){
    event.preventdefault();
    $("span.show_hide").toggleClass("shown hidden");
    $("table").toggleclass("wide narrow");
});
```

And called it using the following code:

```
$(function(){
  $("a[data-toggle-description-length]='toggle'").click(function(event){
    update-ui(event);
    $.get('/toggle_full_details');
  }); 
});
```

But I get `SyntaxError: missing ( before formal parameters`

Latest code attempt at http://jsfiddle.net/38wcndvb/

Comment: `update-ui` not valid name for function. and `toggleclass != toggleClass`

Comment: I tried `update_ui`, `updateUi` and `updateui` for the definition and the call and they all give `is undefined`

Comment: How about `var update-ui = $(function(event){` ?

Comment: Fixed the toggleClass errors. thanks!

Comment: 1. update-ui is incorrect, because function names will have a dash or any sort of special characthers. In JavaScript the convention is to use camelCase, so updateUi would be best. 2. The reason your code is not working even without the dash is that you are declaring your code inside a function, thereby creating it in a scope of its own. When you set the `var updateUi = $(function() {});` you are creating a function that is triggered in `document.ready`, so that might not work as expected. Hence, the best solution is `var updateUi = function (){}`. This should go inside the `$(function(){})`

Comment: Also, only one `$(function(){});` is needed, since this is a shortcut to the `document.ready` event, which should only be triggered once (ideally). Just have one `$(function(){});` and put your code inside of it.

Comment: karthikr thanks but trying that.  nothing happens.  maybe I'm guessing the code wrong. trying lots of different approaches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a couple of errors with your code:

First, `update-ui` should have no dash. In JavaScript, the convention is to use camelCase.

So updateUi would be:

```
var updateUi = function (event) {
   event.preventdDefault();
   $("span.show_hide").toggleClass("shown hidden");
   $("table").toggleClass("wide narrow");
};
```

Ideally, this would go inside your `$(function () {} );` declaration.

```
// You only need one $(function () {} );
// This is a shortcut to the document.ready event
$(function(){ 
  // updateUi will only be available inside the scope of this anonymous function
  var updateUi = function (event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       $("span.show_hide").toggleClass("shown hidden");
       $("table").toggleClass("wide narrow");
  };

  $("a[data-toggle-description-length]='toggle'").click(function(event){
    updateUi(event);
    $.get('/toggle_full_details');
  }); 

  $("a[data-toggle-description-length-refocus]='toggle'").click(function(event){
    updateUi(event);
    $("input[type='text']:first").focus();   // focus
    $.get('/toggle_full_details');
  });
});
```

If you need to make the `updateUi` function available globally, you can just declare it outside your `$(function () {} );`.

Comment: +1 for the approach. Figured it was probably my understanding of scope there.  Unfortunately, I now get TypeError: event.preventdefault is not a function at line 4 (the event.preventdefault() line'.  I kept struggling with event in this myself.

Comment: Forgot to pass on the `event` in the second `updateUi`. Updated the jsfiddle and the response.

Answer (score 1):

Building off the other answer:

- use preventDefault, not default

- use toggleClass, not toggleclass

```
$(function(){
  // updateUi will only be available inside the scope of this anonymous function
  var updateUi = function (event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       $("span.show_hide").toggleClass("shown hidden");
       $("table").toggleClass("wide narrow");
  };  

  $("a[data-toggle-description-length]='toggle'").click(function(event){
    updateUi(event);
    $.get('/toggle_full_details');
  }); 

  $("a[data-toggle-description-length-refocus]='toggle'").click(function(event){
    updateUi(event);
    $("input[type='text']:first").focus();   // focus
    $.get('/toggle_full_details');
  }); 
});
```